# Powershell to compress files and send email

Tags: powershell

Powershell to compress files and send email.

I want to 7zip backup file and send as an email. Below i have done till now which will read text files and send as email. Instead i want to send all the files as email.

```powershell
param (
    [Parameter(Position=0,Mandatory=$true)] [string] $scriptPath

    )

$smtpSvr = "google.com"
$From = "abc@abc.com"
$To = "abc@abc.com"
$Subject = "Check log files attached"

[string]$messagebody = ""

$logs = Get-Content $Path\*.txt

foreach ($log in $logs )
{
    $messagebody = $messagebody + $log + "`r`n"
}

$smtp = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpSvr)
$smtp.Send($From,$To,$Subject,$messagebody)
```

Comment: This question would be better suited over at Stack Overflow.

Comment: Hello, welcome to SU, we're not a script writing service.   Just giving us code for the working part doesn't help any. :)  What have you tried already?  Where exactly are you getting stuck zipping and attaching the logs?  Have you gone over [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.attachment(v=vs.110).aspx) and/or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153126/how-to-create-a-zip-archive-with-powershell) yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use the `Send-MailMessage` cmdlet? With the [zip function from Eld](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153126/how-to-create-a-zip-archive-with-powershell) over at stack overflow and the variables you've declared...

```
function ZipFiles( $zipfilename, $sourcedir )
{
   Add-Type -Assembly System.IO.Compression.FileSystem
   $compressionLevel = [System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel]::Optimal
   [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory($sourcedir, $zipfilename, $compressionLevel, $false)
}

ZipFiles "c:\logfiles.zip" $scriptPath
Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer $smtpSvr -From $From -To $To -Subject $Subject -Attachments "C:\logfiles.zip" -Body $messagebody
```